# How to give an app, running on my own AOSP -eng build, root permissions?

Tags: android, root, android-source, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I'm building Android from source (for a custom ARM-based device).

I have an app, which I want to have root permissions.

In particular, I want my app to be able to run an arbitrary shell command as root.

I've read lots of articles about how to root phones and use other apps, such as SuperSU, to run apps as root.

I have a root shell on the device over adb.

How can I make my app run as root, without installing other apps and performing complicated work-arounds which I believe I do not need?

Comment: An idea would be to create a daemon which runs as root and to send it commands to run. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57199825/signalling-a-root-c-executabke-from-a-non-privileged-java-android-app